# How to open PDF file stored in getFilesDir().getPath() path

Tags: android

I have downloaded a PDF file into my application in the path `getFilesDir().getPath()`

When I try to open the same file using below code :

```
        String path = getBaseContext().getFilesDir().getPath()+"/myfile.pdf";
        File file = new File(path);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);
```

I am getting `The target file doesnot exist` error from pdf reader.

When I browse my device for `myfile.pdf` path, It's located in `"/sdcard/Android/data/com.***.***/files/data/com.***.***/files/myfile.pdf"` .
If I hardcode the above path then also I am getting the same error.

Please let me know how to read file from that path.

Answer (score 0):

use: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/myfile.pdf");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() not working in my case.